# Testing controller create action with polymorphic resource (multiple parents)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I have a Discussion (polymorphic resource) that can belong to Project, Task and Subtask.** I have troubles testing the following create action:

```
 26   def create               
 27     @discussion = @parent.discussions.build(params[:discussion])
 28     @discussion.user_id = current_user.id
 29     if @discussion.save    
 30       current_user.discussions.push(@discussion)
 31       redirect_to [@parent, @discussion], :notice => 'Discussion started' 
 32     else                   
 33       render 'new'         
 34       flash.now[:alert] = 'Unable to start discussion'
 35     end                    
 36   end
```

These are **before filters** that happen before create action (these find the necessary things)

```
 63   private
 64 
 65   def find_cached_parent_or_from_something_id
 66     @parent || find_parent_from_something_id # this does a bit of caching
 67   end
 68 
 69   def find_parent_from_something_id
 70     @parent = nil
 71     params.each do |name, value|
 72       if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
 73         @parent = name.humanize.constantize.find(value)
 74       end
 75     end
 76     @parent
 77   end
 78
 79   def find_project_from_parent_belonging_project
 80     @project = @parent.belonging_project
 81     unless current_user.projects.include?(@project)
 82       redirect_to projects_path
 83       flash[:alert] = msg_page_not_found
 84     end
 85   end
```

As you can see, I can find the parent and all the variables needed. Now this is how my **RSpec controller test for the create action looks like:** They all pass:

```
104         it "can create discussion on project using valid attributes" do                                                                   
105           lambda do
106             post :create, :project_id => project,         
107                           :discussion => valid_attributes
108             flash[:notice].should == 'Discussion started'
109           end.should change(Discussion, :count).by(1)                                                                                     
110         end
111   
112         it "can create discussion on task using valid attributes" do                                                                      
113           lambda do
114             post :create, :task_id => task,               
115                           :discussion => valid_attributes
116             flash[:notice].should == 'Discussion started'
117           end.should change(Discussion, :count).by(1)                                                                                     
118         end
119 
120         it "can create discussion on subtask using valid attributes" do                                                                   
121           lambda do
122             post :create, :subtask_id => subtask,         
123                           :discussion => valid_attributes
124             flash[:notice].should == 'Discussion started'
125           end.should change(Discussion, :count).by(1)                                                                                     
126         end
```

But, I'd prefer to **test creation of discussion on all parents as DRY as possible**, something along the lines of the next test.

```
104         ['project', 'task', 'subtask'].each do |parent|
105           it "can create discussion on #{parent} using valid attributes" do
106             lambda do      
107               post :create, :parent_id => parent,
108                             :discussion => valid_attributes 
109               flash[:notice].should == 'Discussion started'
110             end.should change(Discussion, :count).by(1)
111           end
112         end
```

**How to write this test properly?**

I am using FactoryGirl btw. This test above returns > **NameError: uninitialized constant Parent**

Also, if there is better way/practice of doing this, by all means, correct me :)

EDIT: I have solved the problem using the accepted answer below and have stumbled upon another one, very similar, that I again don't know...

```
142           it "can access show action for discussion for #{parent}" do
143             get :show, :"#{parent}_id" => self.send(parent),
144                        :id => "disucussion_by_another_user_for_#{parent}"    
146             response.should be_successful   
147           end
```

This :id parameter is written wrong... Can you please help me write it properly? (this discussion_by_another_user_for_#{parent} are 3 different factories I defined...)

This is how my factories look like:

```
16   let!(:discussion_by_another_user_for_project) { FactoryGirl.create(:discussion,
 17                                                                      :user => another_user,
 18                                                                      :discussionable => project) }
 19   let!(:discussion_by_another_user_for_task) { FactoryGirl.create(:discussion,
 20                                                                      :user => another_user,
 21                                                                      :discussionable => task) }
 22   let!(:discussion_by_another_user_for_subtask) { FactoryGirl.create(:discussion,
 23                                                                      :user => another_user,
 24                                                                      :discussionable => subtask) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were almost there:

```
["project", "task", "subtask'].each do |parent|
  it "can create discussion on #{parent} using valid attributes" do                                                                      
    lambda do   
      post :create, :"#{parent}_id" => self.send(parent),               
                    :discussion => valid_attributes
      flash[:notice].should == 'Discussion started'
    end.should change(Discussion, :count).by(1)                                                                                     
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

[EDIT] Your extra question: I am not quite sure how you believe handing down a mere string would actually create an object. You create an object with FactoryGirl as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:factory_name)
```

So, if you take that into account, your test becomes:

```
it "can access show action for discussion for #{parent}" do
  discussion_by_another_user = FactoryGirl.create("discussion_by_another_user_for_#{parent}".to_sym)    
  get :show, :"#{parent}_id" => self.send(parent),
      :id => discussion_by_another_user.id
  response.should be_successful   
end
```

Of course, you could inline the parameter `discussion_by_another_user`, but I think this is a bit more readable. Hope this helps.

[EDIT] After clarified question: this is actually *completely* identical that what you asked before.
You build a string, but the string is actually a method you want to call, and as before, you
just write:

```
it "can access show action for discussion for #{parent}" do
  get :show, :"#{parent}_id" => self.send(parent),
             :id => self.send("discussion_by_another_user_for_#{parent}")
  response.should be_successful   
end
```

HTH

Comment: helped and works perfectly. Can you explain why you used this 'self.send(parent)' here? how did you come up with it? what it does? where is it used? thanks!

Comment: Ok, `parent` is a string, which either is project, task or subtask. Note, exactly the method you want to execute. `self` is the current object. In ruby they do not use the word "methods" but messages, so calling a method is actually nothing more than doing `self.send(parent)` (sending the message). Hope that is clear enough? This is just plain ruby. There is a really good book on [meta-programming](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby), this is the area where ruby really shines imho. HTH.

Comment: Have a small additional question... Can you please help ( I have written it in the question edit above ) ?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer accordingly. You should keep in mind the types of the things you are passing around. Strings do not magically turn into objects. The `parent` is a string, to convert into an object, you have either call that method (part 1) or call the factory with that name (part 2). I hope that clarifies things for you a bit.

Comment: thanks. but my factories look differently. I updated the Q accordingly. Sorry, should have written them before...

Comment: You do not see the similarity with what I did before?

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar dilemmas in the past trying to perform "tricks" like that, but you're making the same mistake I was. You should only test for one thing at a time, that way you know what went wrong when the test fails. What you're trying to do is to test 3 different things in one test, which defeats the purpose of the test. You should rather leave 3 "non-DRY" tests that test the things you're testing, rather than 1 DRY test that gets confusing.

That being said, you could try something like this, but if it fails you'd have the problem of having to debug both the test *and* your code, in order to know which was the faulty one:

```
let!(:project) { FactoryGirl.create(:project) }
let!(:task) { FactoryGirl.create(:task) }
let!(:subtask) { FactoryGirl.create(:subtask) }

it "can create discussion on #{parent} using valid attributes" do
  parents = [project, task, subtask]
  parents.each do |parent|
    expect {
      post :create, :parent_id => parent,
                    :discussion => valid_attributes
      flash[:notice].should == 'Discussion started'
    }.to change(Discussion).by(3)
  end
end
```

NOTE: Change "expect" to "lambda" if you're using an older version of RSpec.

Hope this helps

Comment: will try the way you shown it, but what I proposed are 3 separate tests, not just one (id-do-end block is inside each-do block)

Comment: Although I still prefer the less DRY approach when it comes to tests (things are simpler), take a look at the links below. The first one is similar to what you asked (did some more digging up last night cause I found your question interesting :P), and the last 2 are about writing macros to get what you want. Again, I think this is more trouble than it's worth, but different strokes for different folks.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4681988/907299 
http://gusiev.com/2010/11/dynamic-context-in-rspec-dont-repeat-yourself/ 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/157-rspec-matchers-macros

Comment: thanks for all the help and links :) still, the other answer is correct and I'll go with that. check it out and use it it works and creates 3 tests(not 1), each testing different parent. again, thanks for all the effort